# Generic array to int array method call? (Error: The method sort(T[]) in the type (...) is not applicable for the arguments (int[])

Tags: java, arrays, generics, integer, generic-type-argument

For a project, I'm working with an already defined class ('SortingAlgorithms') of different sorting algorithms (separate methods), and I'm trying to call one of the sorting methods from a Main class. I have:

```
int[] selectionArray = new int[10];
SortAlgorithms sort;

sort.selectionSort(selectionArray);
```

Where the header for selectionSort in the SortingAlgo's class looks like this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void selectionSort(T[] data) {
```

When I try to call selectionSort I'm getting this error:

```
The method sort(T[]) in the type SortingAlgorithms is not applicable for the arguments (int[])
```

I guess I'm having trouble with understanding generic types, but from what I can gather shouldn't I be able to pass an int array to a method which defines a generic array?

Comment: I'd suggest you to add a method for each primitive type `sort.selectionSort(int[])` `sort.selectionSort(double[])` etc. just like in the Java's JDK

Comment: Basically you can't get there from here.  The type of `selectionArray` would have to be `Integer[]` for this to work.  You can auto box an `int` but you can't auto box an entire `int[]` array.  You'll need to convert the types manually, declare your array differently or implement a special sort routine for each primitive type you want to sort.  (If you look at `java.util.Arrays` it does the latter.)

Comment: Thank you! I just declared the array as an Integer[] and it worked perfectly!